# Creating text node

Tags: javascript

I have a paragraph

```
<p>Student of Royal Institute!</p>
```

How can I add text within the paragraph using js?

```
<p>Student <script>var textnode = document.createTextNode("Walter"); this.appendChild(textnode);</script> of Royal Institute!</p>
```

So the final output is

```
<p>Student Walter of Royal Institute!</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

A faar better idea would be to use a `<span>` *holder* to put text-values into

```js
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Walter";       // use for HTML
// document.getElementById("name").textContent = "Walter";  // OK for text
```

```html
<p>Student <span id="name"></span> of Royal Institute!</p>
```

---

If you really want to create a `textNode`:

```js
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Walter"); 
document.getElementById("name").appendChild(textnode);
```

```html
<p>Student <span id="name"></span> of Royal Institute!</p>
```

Comment: @Becky you're welcome! (P.S: remember to put your `<script>/*JS here*/</script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert new text into a div. This should work for you:

```
<div id="text">Student of Royal Institute!</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "New text to put into div.";
</script>
```

If you would like you can hook it up to a link like so: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2n5nn5Lm/)